# Ubuntu Studio upgrade mistmatch - 16.04 ended partially 20.04 dev

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 20.04

I was upgrading my ubuntu studio 16.04 and after two rounds of upgrading `do-release-upgrade` I ended up with:

1. my conky telling me I am still 16.04.1.
2. `cat /etc/*release`

   ```
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)"
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
    ID=ubuntu
    ID_LIKE=debian
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)"
    VERSION_ID="20.04"
    HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
    SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
    BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
    PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
    VERSION_CODENAME=focal
    UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
   ```
3. `cat /etc/lsb-release`

   ```
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu 
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04 
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)"
   ```

Can someone help me understanding how I got into this mess and how to sort it out? Everything seems to work. It is just confusing.

Comment: 16.04 will only *release-upgrade* to 18.04.  You then need to reboot and you'll then be running 18.04, and can think about *release-upgrade* again, but not from 16.04.  (16.04 could also *release-upgrade* to 16.10 or off the LTS path; but that's gone as 16.10 is EOL now)

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For 20.04 questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is April 23rd, 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: I understand me being off-topic. My point is that I was not trying to get 20.04. So should I delete for now?

Comment: I cannot see how a 16.04 system would go to 20.04, unless your system was *fraken* already (ie. you had introduced bionic or other packages into it, and thus it wasn't really 16.04 to begin with).  I would probably `sudo apt update` & look at your sources, do a few queries of packages to see what is installed (`apt-cache policy` etc, maybe `ubuntu-support-status` to see when things end; eg. my system reports a good % in april-2025 because my system is *focal*).  Tools are built to go to later automatically, not backwards, so a backup restore is easiest way back, or re-install (esp. desktops)

Comment: Interesting, so i ve messed up somewhere.  `ubuntu-support-status`: You have 448 packages (11.8%) supported until dubna 2025 (Canonical - 5y)
You have 1484 packages (39.0%) supported until dubna 2023 (Canonical - 3y)
You have 301 packages (7.9%) supported until dubna 2023 (Community - 3y)

You have 373 packages (9.8%) that can not/no-longer be downloaded
You have 1203 packages (31.6%) that are unsupported